# Not a valid template while on onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, error, onepage-checkout, template, magento-1.9.2.1

The time I am coming to onepage checkout, I am getting a critical error

> CRIT (2): Not valid template
>   file:frontend/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/design--frontend--base--default--template--checkout--onepage--shipping_method.phtml

Because of this issue, customers are not being able to move to onepage checkout step 'shipping methods' from billing or shipping address.

Can anyone address the possible ways to handle this issue?

NOTE: I am using Magento v1.9.2.1.

Comment: Can you post your xml file as well. I think it is template path issue  more than this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common cause of this error is the use of symlinks without enabling this in the admin area…

```
System > configuration > developer > Template Settings
```

The error gets triggered in `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php` around line 243 ( [see here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L243) ) - so if its not an issue with symlinks then this would be a good place to start debugging.

If you are not using xDebug then where the exception gets caught around line 250 you should either log or var_dump the values of:

```
$includeFilePath
```

and

```
$this->_viewDir
```

Then make sure they both exist (paying attention to the case)

Failing that you might want to look at permissions.

I suspect you have a third party module installed acting as a aitcommonfiles and as the error suggests the template file `design--frontend--base--default--template--checkout--onepage--shipping_method.phtml` does not exist in the location `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/`.

This is a third party module I would re-install it, or find the missing template file and put it in the correct location, or contact the module provider for assistance.

Comment: If you notice then there is no  - -  in the file name

Comment: Man, do you mean the filename shipping_method.p‌​html ?

Comment: I like to mention that filename is shipping_method.p‌​html and not design--frontend--base--default--template--checkout--onepage--shipping_method.p‌​html at the location
That means a directory separation, Isn't it?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I am not having any aitcommonfiles module but I can see an empty directory named aitcommonfiles at design/frontend/base/default/template/
Also, the same code is running fine in live but setting up at staging having same environment is causing this error

Comment: Disable this module from `app/etc/modules` directory. You are missing this file to copy . Check in live as well. `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/` has file on not. Check it your theme as well

Comment: I am not having any module related to it.
Also, /aitcommonfiles/ directory is present in base and nowhere else. Even this is present in live but is not affected at all.

Comment: Then may be clear cache it will fix this issue.

Comment: Clearing cache doesn't fix this
Do I need to remove the empty directory /aitcommonfiles/ ?

Comment: You can remove if there is no any use of it. Check `layout` directory as well. If it contains layout file of this module remove it. You can also disable this module from `app/etc/modules` directory

Comment: I got it solved. Will be posting the answer

Comment: @Rohit Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/design--‌​adminhtml--default--‌​default--template--s‌​ales--order--view--i‌​nfo.phtml I'm getting this exception in my log file. How u var_dump above 2 variables in template.php file

Answer (score 2):

After following many posts, this one played a trick:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110389/magento-not-valid-template-file-page-1column-phtml/12115511#12115511

Approach I followed:
At line no. 250, I just logged `$includeFilePath` and `$this->_viewDir` for both the case, working live site and non-working staging site.
**Observation:** 
 *working site logged:* `/var/ait_patch/design/frontend/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/design--frontend--base--default--template--checkout--onepage--shipping_method.phtml`
 *whereas non-working-site logged nothing inplace.*
 So, I looked into the directory if the file present or not and found that under the directory `var/`, this file was missing `/var/ait_patch/design/frontend/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/design--frontend--base--default--template--checkout--onepage--shipping_method.phtml` 
and adding that file by copying from a working site played the trick.
This was a headbaning as because it was hard to predict that any third party extension can place some files under `var/` directory.
Thanks @Rohit got your effortless help!

Comment: Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/design--adminhtml--default--default--template--sales--order--view--info.phtml I'm getting this exception in my log file.
How u var_dump above 2 variables in template.php file